# Migrating from Elgg to custom developed application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, elgg

I have a social networking platform, which has been built using Elgg. I am now thinking of migrating the application from Elgg to Ruby on Rails/Django.

So for this purpose, I have to do the data migration also. I need some idea, about how should i proceed on this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could use this plugin https://elgg.org/plugins/1939447 which allows you to export all searchable entities to a CSV.

I haven't use it so I can't tell you how it deals with ownership of entities. If it doesn't cover you, you will have to write your own code to export information including ownership details.

In any case you will have to develop code for importing these data in your application.